# Amazon SES Https Api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to use Amazon AWS SES API but they need a signature value which I am creating as shown below in PHP.

```
$algo ="SHA256";
$data = "hello";
$key = "my-access-key";
$signature =  hash_hmac(  $algo , $data , $key  );
```

I am getting an error 
when I am sending https post request .

> ```
> <Message>
> Request must contain a signature that conforms to AWS standards
> </Message>
> ```

Where I am wrong

Answer (score 2):

All AWS API require that every request be signed. However, the signature needs to conform to what is called AWS signature version 4, (which is different from hashing)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

My advice is that you shouldn't try to replicate that process, but use AWS SDK

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/basic-usage.html

Comment: How can I use the https api ? I mean what is the process of signing the request /;

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

At some point after this answer was written, most of the information about Signature Version 3 has been removed from the AWS docs.  The documentation at the link mentioned below is still present, but the page no longer describes how to actually sign requests using Signature Version 3.  It does still mention that SES supports both Signature V3 and V4, but it also states that Signature V4 is recommended.

For the historically curious, the instructions for signing SES requests using Signature Version 3 can still be found at an [archived version of the page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905231547/https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-authentication.html) but using (or switching to) Signature Version 4 would be the future-proof course of action, as it is highly unlikely for Signature V3 to be supported if SES launches any new regions in the future (Signature V2 has not been supported in any region launched since 2014, but SES does not have endpoints in any of those regions).

Signature V3 had significant limitations compared to Signature V4, so it may at some point (or may already) be deprecated and may eventually be discontinued.

tl;dr: Always use Signature Version 4.

<strike>https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-authentication.html explains how to use Signature Version 3 with SES to sign requests you will submit over HTTPS.</strike>

<strike>This is an algorithm that is different from most other AWS services, but is very simple to implement.  The standard Signature V4 is also supported by SES.</strike>